# check if android app is installed at install time

Tags: android, email

I am making an app that receives email from the K9 email client.  I have everything set up.  But I'm having a problem with the permissions.  If my app is installed BEFORE the K9 email app, when they receive an email, my app does not have the correct permission to receive the email.  I have to uninstall/reinstall my app after K9 is installed to get it to work.  Is there any way for me to check if K9 is installed before my app is actually installed.  Or maybe "refresh" the permissions on my app?  I'm kinda at a loss here.  I have no idea even where to begin with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It is currently not possible to *refresh an app's permissions*. Not quite sure what you're doing, but I'm assuming that K-9 declares a permission that you need, and if it isn't present when you install your app then the system simply doesn't grant it to you. You are probably out of luck: my suggestion would be to alert the user that K-9 must be installed before hand and then use an Alarm to periodically check if K-9's install status has changed: if it is added prompt them to uninstall and reinstall.